Google maps in Flutter - how to center the map NOT at the center of the screen
I have a bottom sheet permanently open in the lower half of the screen and the Google map is shown behind it.
How can I set the map center only inside the upper half of the screen?
The goal is to zoom programmatically onto a point, keeping it at the center, but I want to only keep the height bounds to half of the screen.
I am using google_maps_flutter

Please provide a minimal reproducible code that allows to reproduce the issue.

The BottomSheet overlays the map. To achieve what you want, use a widget that sits below the map widget, e.g. using Column. You can style that widget very similar to a BottomSheet, and have it size up when triggered etc, but it needs to be a widget that displaces the Map widget, not overlays it.
